# how to set "--upload-file" parameter of cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, curl

I know that we can upload a file with cURL in PHP easily:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://.....');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file'=>'@/home/myFile.pdf'));
echo curl_exec($c);
```

I have a linux curl command like this:

```
curl --location --upload-file /home/myFile.pdf http://...
```

That works well in a Linux command shell, but in PHP (with the code that I wrote at beginning of my question) I can't upload a file to the url.

I think I must find a way to set "--upload-file" option of the cURL command in PHP.

How can I do this?

Comment: Enable the verbose output and see if you get any errors: `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change the method to PUT:

```
// curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
```

Then change POSTFIELDS to INFILE:

```
// curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file'=>'@/home/myFile.pdf'));
$fp = fopen("/home/myFile.pdf", "rb");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize('/home/myFile.pdf'));
```

Comment: i add `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` as @Cyclone says. when i change the method from post to PUT, the server response says: `400 Bad Request: Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand`

Comment: but when i use post method it says: `411 Length Required`, but i set `Content-Length` in header :|

Comment: @alimzm - Yes but you also set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to false, change this to `true`.

Comment: @alimzm `--upload-file` uses PUT method for upload. Are you sure curl from command line works?

Comment: @Marek - I think the `CURLOPT_INFILE` should be a file handle not a filename. So you would need to do something like `$fp = fopen("/home/myFile.pdf", "rb"); curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);`